# How to set mat radio button selected on print window (Ctrl + P)?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a problem with mat radio button not showing it is selected when opening the print window (ctrl + p), other parts of my page display fine (I'm using ngModel to set value) but the button shows as unchecked (empty) when opening the print although it is checked.

```
<mat-radio-group class="d-flex justify-content-between" [(ngModel)]="dados.finalidade">
    <mat-radio-button class="col-md-auto" value="BENEFICIAMENTO">BENEFICIAMENTO</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button class="col-md-auto" value="REBENEFICIAMENTO">REBENEFICIAMENTO</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button class="col-md-auto" value="ARMAZENAMENTO">ARMAZENAMENTO</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

If anyone knows any solution please tell me!

**UPDATE!!**

I put this on my style.scss and my problem are solved:

```
@media print {
  .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #00695C inset !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this on my style.scss and my problem are solved:

```
@media print {
  .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #00695C inset !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my own page, I found it to just be a matter of the "Print Background Graphics" being turned off in Chrome. The fix was to add the following to my stylesheet:

```
 -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
```

Comment: webkit-print-color-adjust only works for webkit browers, color-adjust also works in Firefox (but still doesn't work in IE11 though).